# ESLint not working with ngDoc names - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint, jsdoc, ngdoc

I am creating documentation for an AngularJS app using ngDoc(dgeni), the documentation is generated correctly but the ESLint shows `JSDoc syntax error  valid-jsdoc`, of course I don't want to disable this rule because is really helpful when there is some function with params without documentation, but when the documentation is correct ESLint detects the name as incorrect when they have `:`, example:

```
myModule.controller:myController
myModule.module:myModule
myModule.filter:myFilter
myModule.directive:myDirective
...
```

but there is not error when I remove the ':' example:

```
myModule.controllermyController
```

but of course this is not valid ngDoc and it is not taken correctly when I generate de HTML doc.

Is there any way to solve this issue?.

Comment: I'm using this syntax: https://github.com/idanush/ngdocs/wiki/API-Docs-Syntax